# pymysql.err.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '8207' for key 'agentId'")

Tags: python, mysql

> "insert into agentattribute(agentid,attributeRefURL,attributeName,attributeValue,Operation,attributeOldValue) values (" + live_agent_id + ",'" + live_entry + "','" +live_name_value_array[0] + "','" + live_name_value_array[1] + "', 'Added' ,',')")

Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message explains, `agentId` column has primary key/unique constraint on it and value `8207` already exists.

In this case, you can go ahead with one of the below options:

- Update the record if the value already exists
- Propogate the error message back to User Interface/application

Comment: or 3. delete the row that throws the error and start again.